# hook_block_view() throwing warnings in common.inc and output not rendering

Tags: 7, blocks

I am developing a custom module that makes a number of remote calls to a proprietary API and then displays the results. The API call part is working fine and I am getting back the data I would expect. I am having a problem with rendering the result into a template. When hook_block_view tries to return the block I get the following block of warnings and nothing displayed. Note I am developing under XAMPP although I have tested on an Ubuntu server and I get teh same result

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in element_children() (line 6525 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\includes\common.inc).
    Warning: Illegal string offset '#children' in drupal_render() (line 5982 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\includes\common.inc).
    Warning: Illegal string offset '#children' in drupal_render() (line 5992 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\includes\common.inc).
    Warning: Illegal string offset '#children' in drupal_render() (line 6030 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\includes\common.inc).
    Warning: Illegal string offset '#printed' in drupal_render() (line 6037 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\includes\common.inc).
```

My hook_block_view is as follows

```
function reservation_block_view($delta = '', $arg0 = '', $arg1 = '') {
  $block = array();

  $function = $arg0;
  $kioskID = $arg1;


  switch ($delta) {
    case 'reservation':
      if ($function == 'locker-availability') {
        // Get the url from the database
        $availabilityurl = variable_get('sgauth_base_url_reservation_locker_availability', '');
        // Add the http headers
        $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');
        // Put the whole request together
        $options = array('headers' => $headers, 'method' => 'GET');
        // Make the request and return a result
        $result = drupal_http_request($availabilityurl . '/' . $kioskID, $options);
        $title = 'Locker Availability';
      }
      elseif ($function == 'price') {
        // Get the url from the database
        $priceurl = variable_get('sgauth_base_url_reservation_price', '');
        // Add the http headers
        $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');
        // Put the whole request together
        $options = array('headers' => $headers, 'method' => 'GET');
        // Make the request and return a result
        $result = drupal_http_request($priceurl . '/' . $kioskID, $options);
        $title = 'Locker Price';

      }
      else {
        // Get the url from the database
        $reservationurl = variable_get('sgauth_base_url_reservation', '');
        // Add the http headers
        $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');
        // Put the whole request together
        $options = array('headers' => $headers, 'method' => 'GET');
        // Make the request and return a result
        $result = drupal_http_request($reservationurl . '/' . $kioskID, $options);
        $title = 'Reservation';
      }
      break;
  }
  // Just for testing
  dpm($result);

  if (in_array($result->code, array(200, 304))) {
    $result = drupal_json_decode($result->data);
    $vars = array();
    $vars['title'] = $title;

    $vars['data'] = $result;
    $vars['data']['Data']['kisokID'] = $kioskID;

    $block['content'] = theme('reservation', $vars);
  }
  return $block;
}
```

My hook_block_info and hook_theme are

```
function reservation_block_info() {
  $blocks['reservation'] = array(
    'info' => t('SingPost POP Station Reservation'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
  );
  return $blocks;
}


function reservation_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'reservation' => array(
      'template' => 'reservation',
      'variables' => array('title' => NULL, 'data' => NULL),
    )
  );
}
```

And finally my template reservation.tpl.php just for testing at this stage is

```
<h2><?php print $title; ?></h2>
```

I get this warning block when I flush all caches.

I am getting valid data back in the result array from the API call

From working my way through the code I have found that if I comment out the line

```
$block['content'] = theme('reservation', $vars);
```

in the hook_block_view I am not getting the warnings but obviously I am also not getting what I want because I am not using the block

I am not sure what I am doing wrong with the block and would really appreciate some help from the community

Regards

Richard

Comment: What are you using to render your `$block['content']`. I usually get these errors with incorrect usage of `print drupal_render()` (on a variable that is not structured correctly). Maybe try using `print render()` or just `print` instead.

Comment: Put your `$block['content'] = theme('reservation', $vars);` inside switch. See the example here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7. Only the `return $block;` should be outside the `switch`.